# How to get month name from date in datastage?

Tags: datastage

I have added example as below :

> input : 31-12-2019
>
> output :31-dec-2019

How to get the month name from month number in Data stage?
Is there any function in data stage to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [date format options](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.adref.doc/topics/r_deeadvrf_date_Formats.html)

%mmm would return "Dec" for your case - if you you really need it lower case as shown in your example you could also use string functionality to substring and concat it manually.
Like

```
datefield[1,3] : "dec" : datefield[7,5]
```